# joining two numbered list in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

```
NO *compare(NO *head1, NO *head2) {
    NO *temp = NULL;
    NO *tmp = NULL;
    NO *head = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    for (temp = head1; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        for (tmp = head2; tmp->next != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
            if (tmp->val <= temp->val) {
                head = new_node(tmp->val, i, head);
                i++;
            }
            printf("0");
        }
        head = new_node(temp->val, i , head);
        i++;
    }

    return head;
}
```

"the function was intended to take two sorted linked list and create a list without  repetition and sorted in ascending order"

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: the question is what is the logical error

Comment: you have to mention the error you are getting in expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is logical error. think over it

1. There may be same node added a lot of times.
2. few elements may not come at all.

trying solving the problem using one for loop. i.e traverse both the list when one of it hits NULL, come out check which is null and append the elements from other list which is not null till it encounters null.

this problem is more like combining array in give it a look

> MERGE SORT

try this logic

```
      for(initialization; temp->link != NULL || tmp->link != NULL;)
      {
           // check which is greater
           // copy that into new list
          // accordingly increment that pointer(temp or tmp) 
      }
      if(temp->link == NULL)
      {
          // copy elements of second list till elements are remaining 
      }
      else if(tmp->link == NULL)
      {
           // copy the elements of first list till elements are remaining
      }
```

Comment: i have to merge both list like if one list is 1 3 5 4 and other one is 2 6 7 8, the new list must be 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8

Comment: there is a problem with the logic that if the two list are 1359 and 2367 the final list will contain 13592367

Comment: don't increment both the pointers. increment only the pointer which has smaller element. update the code u have done.

Comment: thanks @const, your solution did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
NO *merge(NO *head1, NO *head2){
    NO *head = NULL;
    NO *current, *select;

    while(head1 != NULL || head2 != NULL){
        if(!head2 || head1 &&  head1->i < head2->i){
            select = head1;
            head1 = head1->nextp;
        } else if(!head1 || head2 && head2->i < head1->i){
            select = head2;
            head2 = head2->nextp;
        } else if(head1 && head2 && head1->i == head2->i){
            select = head1;
            head1 = head1->nextp;
            head2 = head2->nextp;
        }
        NO *new_node = malloc(sizeof(NO));
        new_node->val = select->val;
        //new_node->next = NULL;
        if(head==NULL){
            current = head = new_node;
        } else {
            current->next = new_node;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    current->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: the function works all good but it still shows repetition

Comment: @shubham9182 ah! Is there any overlap in the two lists of the base?

Comment: yes there is and for that you have to make a slight change in the function like don't use <= amd >= just use < and >, and use this extra condition

Comment: else if (head1 && head2){
            select = head1;
            head1 = head1->next;
            head2 = head2->next;
        }

Comment: @shubham9182 I think it is a good modified version if it.

Comment: sorry i didn't see  your sedited version

Comment: @shubham9182 no problem.
we have the time difference.

Comment: @shubham9182 Please close the question by accept(✓) if this solved.

Comment: @shubham9182 _yes there is_ E.g head1 : 1,2,2,3 ?